# Obfuscate rest response using bson

Tags: java, jquery, rest, bson

I am using REST API for searching. When an ajax call is fired, REST returns json from Java code

```
return JResponse.ok(searchResult).build() //searchResult is List of Custom object
```

In javascript I would stringfy that json and parse to show relevant data on screen.

```
var search = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Now I want to secure/obfuscate json response returned from REST, so that anyone who directly hits APIs won't get readable response. I tried [bson](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master/src/main/org/bson) but bot able to implement it successfully. Didn't find much support on how to put collection object in bson and how to retrieve it back in JS while googling.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go with tokens.

Every time when request made to server request must contain a token which change for every request as well check that the request header for **ajax request**. If it is an ajax request then and then only return result. Also add rule for **no cross browser access**.

I think if you did it your data will not be accessible to anyone by direct http request.